# Пропуск пустых строк

Tags: c#

Как игнорировать пустые строки из TextFile когда они находятся между и после строк?
[image: Ошибка]
Формат TextFile:

```
2016-01-01 20:23;Work;5;чистка;5000.00  
2016-01-03 00:40;Custom;1;2;6;3

2016-01-03 00:41;Custom;1;1;10;1
```

48 строка `if (element[1] == "Card")`

А вот сам код:

```
public void SplitAndQuery(string path)
{
    char[] separatorLines = { '\n' };
    char[] separatorWords = { ';' };
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default).Split(separatorLines, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length - 1; i++)
    {
      string[] element = lines[i].Split(separatorWords, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (element[1] == "Card")
        {
            if (checkCard(element[2]) == false)
            {
                insertCard(element[2], element[3], element[4], element[5], element[6], element[7], element[8]);

                if (checkDiscount(element[2]) == "-1")
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("ups");
                }
                else
                {
                    insertDiscount(element[0],element[9]);
                }
            }
            else if (checkCard(element[2]) == true)
            {
                updateCard(element[3], element[4], element[5], element[6], element[7], element[8], element[2]);
                if (checkDiscount(element[2]) == "-1")
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("ups");
                }
                else
                {
                    insertDiscount(element[0],element[9]);
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: проблема не в пустых строках, а в том, что в строках не одинаковое количество _слов_, в некоторых есть _element[5], element[6]_ в некоторых их нет, и в этом месте все падает

Comment: Отображено не весь TextFile. Все работает когда нету в TextFile пустых строк. Как только добавлю в конец файла \n то программа не работает.

Comment: это неважно, как только попадается строка в которой мало элементов, а ты пытаешься получить, как будто у нее много - ты получаешь свою ошибку

Comment: кстати не плохо было бы отметить строку 48, на которую указывается в ошибке

Comment: Попробуйте так `char[] separatorLines = { '\r', '\n' };`

Comment: большое спасибо Dmitry, заработало.

Comment: @Dmitry оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что ж так сложно то. File.ReadAllLines.Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)); чем не угодил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В некоторых ОС, например, Microsoft Windows, в качестве перевода строки используется сочетание кодов возврата каретки `CR` (`\r`) и перевода строки `LF` (`\n`).
Чтобы исправить приведенный в вопросе пример, достаточно добавить символ `\r`

```
char[] separatorLines = { '\r', '\n' };
```

Более правильным вариантом, по моему мнению, будет использование [`Environment.NewLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx)
Например, так

```
char[] separatorLines = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте добавить проверку

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(lines[i]){
return;
}
```

сразу после

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= lines.Length - 1; i++)
{
```

Comment: Вместо `return;`, наверное, лучше `continue;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Читать все строки из текстового файла - плохо. Почему? Гуглите.
2. Если вы точно знаете структуру данных лучше использовать регулярные выражения.

В конкретно вашем вопросе ошибка в 48 строке возникает потому вы пытаетесь разделить пустую строку. Метод Split если не найдет разделителя в строке вернет массив с 1 элементом - исходной строкой. И тогда при обращении по индексу 2 вы выйдете за пределы массива. Чтобы избежать такой ситуации просто проверте колво элементов в массиве после Split по свойству Length.